# Is there a way to get GPU acceleration on Raspberry Pi 4 for Deep Learning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, gpu, tensorflow-lite, raspberry-pi4

On the official Tensorflow Lite website they show the support for GPU acceleration for Android and iOS but they don't say anything about support for Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Rasperry Pi for **training** of neural nets within a mainstream framework, such as TensorFlow or PyTorch, you will likely not obtain GPU acceleration in a near term. The reason is that at least those two are mainstream GPU-centric, mostly NVidia, with AMD support being enabled little by little ([here](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2018/08/amd-rocm-gpu-support-for-tensorflow.html) for TF and [here](https://lernapparat.de/pytorch-rocm/) for Torch).

Arguably, the most promising option for Pi is [OpenCL support](https://missinglink.ai/guides/tensorflow/tensorflow-support-opencl/), however, by the time of writing and up to my knowledge, there is no OpenCL implementation for Raspberry Pi 4 yet.

Possibly with [TensorFlow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/train_models) you can get something of the Raspberry Pi GPU, as far as it can use GPU by means of WebGL shaders. Therefore, a web-browser having WebGL support running on Pi may enable the GPU-accelerated training.

If you want to use Raspberry Pi for **inference**, it might be easier to benefit from the GPU acceleration.

- [ncnn](https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn) is a library using Vulkan API enabling GPU acceleration for Raspberry Pi 4.
- [Beatmup](https://github.com/lnstadrum/beatmup/) library enables a GPU-accelerated inference on all Raspberry Pi models, not only 4. It also offers some conversion tools from Keras models, but is quite constrained in terms of implemented features.

Comment: ncnn is yet to support vulkan in raspberry pi 4

Comment: here is a good review of many SW platforms: https://qengineering.eu/deep-learning-software-for-raspberry-pi-and-alternatives.html It says that Alibaba MNN is the fastest framework for a Raspberry Pi 4.